# Cannot set an input tag's "value" using a PHP variable

Tags: php, html

EDIT:  Here is the code that sets the PHP variable "photofilename":

```
   $photofilename = "C:\XAMPP\htdocs\ourWEbSite\images\coolPhoto.jpg"
```

I also tried this to make sure this wasn't a 'displaying a server file path in an input in the browser" security issue, and I get the same error message:

```
  $photofilename = "HELLO";    //  this gives the same error message!
```

ORIGINAL POST: 
I'm trying to set the "value"  on an input tag with a PHP variable and it is generating this error:

```
   <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: photofilename in <b>C:\XAMPP\htdocs\ourWEbSite\pageFour.php</b> on line <b>372</b><br />
```

Despite this error -- just one line above the html input tag that generates this error, I **successfully** use the exact same PHP variable in an **img** tag and the image appears on the page.

Here's the code:

```
      <img id='theSelectedImage' src='<?php echo $photofilename ?>' />
      <input type="text" id="theSubjectOne" style="width: 350px" value='Is-this-text-visible'/></br>     
      <input type="text" id="theSubjectTwo" style="width: 350px" value='<?php echo $photofilename ?>'/>
```

Here's what I see on the page:

(1) I see the photograph **photofilename** rendered successfully in the img tag;

(2) I see an input tag filled with *'Is-this-text-visible'*;

(3) I see an input tag filled with:  
****Notice**:  Undefined variable: photofilename in **C:\XAMPP\htdocs\ourWEbSite\pageFour.php** on line **372****

Is there something about *not* being able to set the 'value' of an input tag using a PHP variable?   I know, with certainty, that the 'photofilename'  PHP variable IS, in fact, defined, because I use it just above the input tag in an img tag and it renders correctly.

Comment: Add the contents of photofilename variable so everyone can see what it contains

Comment: Could you add paste all of your code in here ?

Comment: Please post the full php code that uses photofilename. Have in mind, the PHP variables are case sensitive. So photoFilename and photofilename is not the same variable. Also maybe you are unsetting the variable at some point. The operation you are doing, works just fine in PHP and HTML, there is no technical reason why it should not work, except a typo in the code or well, some kind of a bug, maybe you are populating the var from a GET or POST, and it works the first time, but after refresh it occurs.In any case, the full code would be helpful to identify the bug, you can redact sensitive info.

Comment: I added to my question the setting of the PHP variable photofilename -- see above.

Comment: It is not possible this is the full code: <?php $photofilename = "HELLO";?> <img id='theSelectedImage' src='<?php echo $photofilename ?>' />
      <input type="text" id="theSubjectOne" style="width: 350px" value='Is-this-text-visible'/></br>     
      <input type="text" id="theSubjectTwo" style="width: 350px" value='<?php echo $photofilename ?>'/> this works.

Comment: i made the same as @Sinisa Valentic and works too.

Answer (score 0):

Does it works like this ?

```
<?php $photofilename = "..."; echo $photofilename; ?>
```

If that all doesen't work just set it again before your variable it might seem retarded but if you need a quik fix oh well.

Comment: @CFHcoder Did you add the semi-colon to *both* of the echo statements? The first line won't produce an error but the second line could throw it because the first line was un-parsed.

Comment: @sjagr Yes, both have the semicolon -- no change, I can see the photo, but the input tag is filled with "Error:  photofilename is undefined" which, by the fact that the photo IS IN FACT visible, I know this error message is wrong.

Comment: I tried that and it works.  Why then when I set photofilename to "HELLO" it still generates an error I do not understand.  And why the photo represented by 'photofilename' in the img tag appears  on the page fine,  but just below that, the input tag says the exact same 'photofilename' is undefined?  HOW?

Comment: Well you could your full code :) ? The whole page you have, it's a tad difficult to help you out else.

Comment: You are just wasting everyones time not providing the required information to solve your problem.

Comment: Please take a pass on this if you so feel, as my original question has been answered -- no one has remarked that using a PHP variable to set the "value" in an **input** tag is a no-no.  That was my original question, and it has been answered so I now have a different problem (a weird scoping issue), obviously, so I'm working on it,  and thanks for your help.  By the way, I have no Javascript that is dynamically changing the **img** or the troublesome **input** tag, if that's what your "show us more code** question was.

Answer (score 0):

check your code if you don't get your variable repopulated somewhere between 1st and 2nd line of

```
    <?php echo $photofilename ?>
```

the code you posted definitely works: check it on http://phpfiddle.org/

```
  <?php $photofilename='lalala';?>
  <img id='theSelectedImage' src='<?php echo $photofilename ?>' />
  <input type="text" id="theSubjectOne" style="width: 350px" value='Is-this-text-visible'/></br>     
  <input type="text" id="theSubjectTwo" style="width: 350px" value='<?php echo $photofilename ?>'/>
```

Answer (score -1):

The second line ends with an incorrect tag: `</br>`. It should be `<br>`. Can't see why that would produce a PHP error, but it's a start.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Prefer it to be a comment rather than an answer? That makes sense actually.

Comment: I didn't downvote but incorrect html tags wont cause the php error, it will simply be ignored, therefore no real value to the issue OP has

Comment: It is not an answer and does not solve OP's problem in any manner or form, nor does it even remotely help, since a PHP error is independent to HTML markup (unless stray HTML markup was accidentally put anywhere inside of `<?php ?>` tags.) Most modern browsers will convert `</br>` to `<br>` or `<br />` with absolutely no difficulty as well.

Comment: @HenryBlyth Please delete this answer, and, if you feel that it's useful, add it as a comment on the question.